# Create a PDF using android PrintedPdfDocument class from a recyclerview?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

See the code below  which i am using to generate PDF from a recyclerview .

```
@TargetApi(19)
private void writePDFDocument() {

    final File file = new File(getStorageDir("PDF"), "sample.pdf");
    int PDF_PAGE_WIDTH = 595, PDF_PAGE_HEIGHT = 842;


    // create a new document
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

    //Get Content View.
    View contentView = recyclerView;

    // crate a page description
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.
            Builder((int) PDF_PAGE_WIDTH, (int) PDF_PAGE_HEIGHT, 1).create();

    // start a page
    PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);

    // draw view on the page
    Canvas pageCanvas = page.getCanvas();
    int pageWidth = pageCanvas.getWidth();
    int pageHeight = pageCanvas.getHeight();
    int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    contentView.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight);
    contentView.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
    contentView.draw(pageCanvas);

    // finish the page
    pdfDocument.finishPage(page);

    try {
        pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // close the document
    pdfDocument.close();
    // Set on UI Thread
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrintPDFSample.this);
            builder.setTitle("Success")
                    .setMessage("PDF File Generated Successfully.")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }).show();
        }
    });

}
```

From the above code i was able to generate PDF . My actual problem is that the PDF generated contains only visible item in the screen. If i increase the page height i can see the entire items . But i need to generate multiple A4 pages instead of increasing PDF height . I am aware that there is a lib called iText for generating PDF but its only free for personal use .

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: I know its late still may be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545782/creating-pdf-file-using-itext-from-a-recyclerview-entire-items-inside-in-andro